# Populating instance variables in rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, stubbing

I have a class which has the following initialise method.

```
def initialize(my_var)
  @my_var = my_var
end
```

and I want to test the method which then does something to `@my_var`

```
def split
  @my_var.split(",")
end
```

how do I change `@my_var` before testing that it returns an array properly?

Is this possible without having an accessor for `@my_var`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a correct practice.  Rspec should be testing the interface behavior of your classes and models - not the internal implementation (of which instance variables undoubtedly are).  There are ways to do this, but are you sure you don't want to have an accessor for that variable?

Anyhow, you can use `my_object.instance_variable_get("@my_var")` and `my_object.instance_variable_set("@my_var", value)` to manipulate the variable.

Comment: the reason i'm doing this is that my initialize method is reading from file, what I'm trying to do is stub `File` and write the expected processed data from that file without needing a file to support my tests. I can then skip that initialize method for testing any other methods in my class.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech, you can also try using StringIO instead of file